# Formula results for LOWER() are not displayed

Tags: excel, worksheet-function

I'm simply trying to apply the LOWER formula from one column to another:

In cell F2 I put this

```
=LOWER(E2)
```

But all I get in F2 is this: =LOWER(E2), instead of the actual lowercase version of the word in E2.

(I'm on a mac. Is there some kind of setting to have it display the results of a formula? Numerical formulas correctly display the results)

Comment: check your cell format isn't text...

Comment: The formate of both cells is Text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not on Mac to check this, but AFAIK having cell format set to Text makes Excel not process formulas. Please try these steps:

1. change the format of F2 from Text to General
2. rewrite the formula in F2 (or just reedit it by adding some space) and press Enter

I hope it works for you.

Andrei